# Wait till the GeckoFX Webbrowser has loaded

Tags: c#, browser, pageload, geckofx

I want to automate a few tasks on my website with GeckoFX for some testing.
That should happen when I click a button and everything should be automated after that button click.
This includes clicking buttons where the page refreshes so the code has to wait till the page has loaded and that's where my problem is.

If I do it like that:

```
geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("http://mywebsite.com");
GeckoInputElement searchText = new GeckoInputElement(geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByName("searchbox")[0].DomObject);
            searchText.Value = "GeckoFx";
```

I get an error, so how can I put it that the code after .Navigate waits till the webbrowser has fully loaded the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `DocumentCompleted` Method to perform your automatic operations.

```
private void geckoWebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
          // Here you can add the coding to perform after document loaded
    }
```

For example : First initiate the browser to google page by `geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.com");`

After google page loaded you can do the following in document_completed method:

```
GeckoInputElement search =new GeckoInputElement(geckoWebBrowser2.Document.GetElementsByName("q")[0].DomObject);
        GeckoInputElement button = new GeckoInputElement(geckoWebBrowser2.Document.GetElementsByName("btnG")[0].DomObject);
        search.focus();
        search.Value = "Master Blaster Sachin";            
        button.Click();
```

so it will search the value you given automatically after the google page loaded. Like that you can modify the program as per your logic. Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

I would go an use a product like Selenium http://seleniumhq.org/. It's free open source web testing which is scriptable.

Comment: What engine does that use and are proxies supported?